# Augment the markdown syntax with some lightweight TeX-ish conventions

Tags: feature-request, markup

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can we get SmartyPants?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/328/can-we-get-smartypants)

Some examples that have been proposed is to be able to type ``quotes'' for educated “quotes”, as well as -- and --- for en- and em-dashes.

Note this would be *outside* of any specialized parsing/evaluation of TeX markup as [suggested  in another thread](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7/we-need-tex-markup). My suggestion here is to add **some very light markup** to use when editing the main text of the questions/answers.

**Edit:** I should have added that this comes from other suggestions [in another thread](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23/what-should-the-site-design-look-feel-smell-like) about the look/feel of the site, and we thought it was important to stress the fact that, in this site, *we do care* about typography. That's why easier methods to input educated quotes and dashes should be welcomed.

Also, this should not interfere with other TeX markup, which should be probably clearly delimited by `$...$` or some other kind of markers.

Comment: I think we've been doing fine with Markdown as is...

Comment: I've edited the question adding why some people think this would be a desirable feature to have.

Comment: I would also argue that people have been doing fine with Word as is.. but that is not the point.

Comment: Isn’t this a duplicate of http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/328/can-we-get-smartypants/ (or rather, the other way round, but I prefer the other request)? If so, can it be closed?

Answer (score 3):

Please don't add anything that tries to parse Tex-like markup. It will interfere with Tex code in questions and answers.

Comment: This shouldn't be an issue, because TeX code should be clearly delimited as I just clarified in the suggestion.

Comment: "This shouldn't be an issue" scares me.